# Как правильно сделать делегирование?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день. Может кто помочь с пояснением? Есть три одинаковых блока с кнопкой, при клике по кнопке именно этому блоку добавить класс, а не всем сразу. И снова при клике по всему блоку класс удаляется, только это происходит после того, как убрали курсор с блока. Не могу понять алгоритм действий. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/16fn7oes/9/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').on('click', this, function () {
        $('.red').toggleClass('active');
        $('.green').slideToggle();

    });

});
```

```css
.items {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%;
}
.etem {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.red {
   background: red;
     width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.green {
   background: green;
     width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.active {
   background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Первая часть вопроса - ясна. Добавить класс блоку, на котором произошел клик. А вот этот совсем непонятно "И снова при клике по всему блоку класс удаляется, только это происходит после того, как убрали курсор с блока."

Comment: Т.е мы кликаем второй раз по всему блоку и класс удаляется именно у этого блока, это действие происходит после ухода курсора мыши с блока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `this`, чтобы действия применялись именно на тот блок и кнопку, по которому кликаете. Через методы `closest` и `find` находите те элементы, которые хотите изменить.

Также при клике можно назаначить событие `mouseleave` на весь блок, при котором произойдут обратные действия, когда мышь покинет область блока.

Опять же при клике на кнопку событие `mouseleave` будет отменяться.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('.item').click(function (e) {    
      if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON'){
          $(this).closest('.item').find('.red').addClass('active');
          $(this).closest('.item').find('.green').slideDown();
          $(this).off("mouseleave");
          return
      }
      
      $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.red').removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.green').slideUp();
      })      
    });
});
```

```css
.items {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%;
}
.etem {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.red {
   background: red;
     width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.green {
   background: green;
     width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.active {
   background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <button>click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!